# How to extract text from cells with distinct

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula

I tried different approaches to accomplish what I am looking for and it might not be possible with how I have formated my data but I will try to explain it to see if there is a way.

My origin of data looks like the following:

| Case | HELP |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | HELP-01 | HELP-02 |
| 101 | HELP-01 |  |
| 102 |  |  |
| 103 | HELP-03 |  |

What I want is to be able to extract the `HELP-*` into another column without duplicate values and one after another. The result I am looking for is from the above table been able to have this:

| HELP |
| --- |
| HELP-01 |
| HELP-02 |
| HELP-03 |

Is there a way to do this in Google Sheets?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively you can use:

```
=UNIQUE(QUERY(FLATTEN(B2:C),"where Col1 like 'HELP-%'"))
```

The `QUERY()` will now only return those values that start with 'HELP-' in the case you might have other string-values.

A littel more specific even, could be to use:

```
=UNIQUE(QUERY(FLATTEN(B2:C),"where Col1 matches 'HELP-\d+'"))
```

Where 'matches' will now use the regular expression to only return values that start with 'HELP-' but end with any 1+ digits.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. This indeed does the trick!

Answer (score 1):

Try this in Google Sheets

```
=sort(array_constrain(unique(flatten(B2:C)),counta(B2:C),1))
```

Comment: Your answer works but it has a flaw it duplicates the values, it doesn't distinguish among them. In this sense, all the values will be listed even duplicates...

Comment: Thx, I have added `unique` in my answer